# Add slide to toggle

Tags: javascript, toggle, slide

I am trying to add a slide effect to my toggle script

```
<script>
    function clickitems() {
        // action 1
        if( document.getElementById('spoiler2').style.display=='none' ){
            document.getElementById('spoiler2').style.display='block';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('spoiler2').style.display='none';
        };
        // action 2
        if( document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display=='block' ){
            document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

But so far without success, can anyone help me out ? Much appreciated

The elements spoiler and spoiler2 are simple div elements

```
<div id="spoiler" style="width:300px;height:100%;display:none;"> Txt and image Content</div>
<div id="spoiler2" style="width:300px;height:100%;display:none;"> Txt and image Content</div>
```

The buttons are `<a class="button"  onclick="clickitems()">Items</a>`

And yes i could have gone with a paragraph tag instead of a link

Comment: You should also post your html.

Comment: its a simple div element, just a sec ill add it

Comment: By slide effect, you mean like this: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp?

Comment: yes exactly like the jQuery slideToggle()

Comment: just that my div has a margin-top, so the toggle starts at the beggining of the outer margin, instead of the inside element :(

Comment: You can do a lot with CSS3 animations [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/2vLjU/3457/).

Comment: You should have gone further with your code before asking here.

Comment: actually thanks to you i changed the javascript to jquery, and after a bit of testing and editing it is working. so thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so far i got this,

A JavaScript to close the other and Jquery open element while toggling the selected element

```
<script>
    function clickitem() {

        if( document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display=='block' ){
            document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none';
        }
    }
</script> </p>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#spoiler2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```